# SwiftUI - Tapping a Button changes VStack's background color

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

When I tapped OrderButton, all the VStack's background color is changing to gray color then turning back like assigned a click event. How can I prevent this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct DrinkDetail : View {

    var drink: Drink

    var body: some View {

        List {

            ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                Image(drink.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 80)
                    .opacity(0.25)
                    .blur(radius: 10)
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                        Text(drink.name)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        Text("It is just for $5.")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    Spacer()
                }

            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(drink.description)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .font(.body)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .lineSpacing(12)

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    OrderButton()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)

            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}


struct OrderButton : View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Order Now")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.headline)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct DrinkDetail_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DrinkDetail(drink: LoadModule.sharedInstance.drinkData[3])
    }
}
#endif
```

The issue resolved by using **ScrollView** and adding some more parameters for auto resize of **Text**:

```
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

            ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                Image(drink.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 80)
                    .opacity(0.25)
                    .blur(radius: 10)
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                        Text(drink.name)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        Text("It is just for $5.")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    Spacer()
                }

            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(drink.description)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .font(.body)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .lineSpacing(12)
                    .padding(Edge.Set.leading, 15)
                    .padding(Edge.Set.trailing, 15)

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    OrderButton()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)

            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the UI you are trying to get? Because, from your example, it seems that `List` is not necessary. Indeed, `List` is:

> A container that presents rows of data arranged in a single column.

If you don't really need `List` you can replace it with `VStack` (if your content must fit the screen) or with a `ScrollView` (if your content is higher than the screen). Replacing the `List` will solve your issue that depends on the list selection style of its cells.

An alternative, if you need to use the `List` view is to set the selection style of the cells in the `SceneDelegate` to `none` (but this will affect all of your `List` in the project) this way:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let contentView = ContentView() //replace this with your view

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none

        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I just want to make a detail page. So, Using `ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false)` is more logic way. Some more parameters are needed for Text. I will add with changes below question for others. Also nice to know a different solution for preventing that selection issue too. Thanks.